# How to get MenuItems from ContributionItems within MenuManager?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I have a MenuManager that is filled with Actions, is it possible to access the corresponding MenuItem for the action (ContributionItem)  ?

```
MenuManager menuManager = new MenuManager("#PopupMenu", "contextMenu");
menuManager.add(IAction1...);
menuManager.add(IAction2...);

Menu menu = menuManager.createContextMenu(myTreeVvewer.getControl());
myTreeVvewer.getControl().setMenu(menu);

myTreeVvewer.getTree().addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

     public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
          //Iterate menu items of menu and set something... 


      }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Add listeners, or modify the items that are present when the context menu opens?

Answer (score 3):

It would probably be easier to use the option `MenuManager#.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);` and then dynamically add the menu items in a `IMenuListener`.

Comment: If you want different items to appear in the context menu based on the selection, this is the way to go.